# What is proper syntax for mysqldb to avoid sql-injection?

Tags: html, flask, mysql-python

I'm building a web application via the Flask framework, and am trying to use html forms to retrieve user data which will ultimately be stored in a mysqldb database.

I initially was passing my python variables into the sql command with a "%" instead of a "," like so:

```
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO %s (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")' % (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6)
```

This method worked flawlessly, but then I wised up and realized while debugging my application that this is extremely susceptible to sql-injection and that I needed to use the "," instead.  So I changed the code to this:

```
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6)
```

According to everything I've read on here, google, youtube, etc., this would've been a fix all method to my problem, which I'm sure it is, but a new sql syntax problem arises which I can't seem to fix no matter what I try to do.

My html form that this is all related to looks like this:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" required></li>
    <li><select name="activity" required>
                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                    <option value="Food/Drink">Food/Drink</option>
                    <option value="Liesure">Liesure</option>
                    <option value="Night Life">Night Life</option>
                    <option value="Scenic">Scenic</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select></li>
    <li><textarea id="post" name="content" placeholder="Write post here..." required></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"></li>
```

I'm using **request.form["html_name"]** in my python code to assign the user inputs to variables for all of the user inputs except for the image one, which I use **request.files['image']** for instead. I'm not actually inserting the image into the database though,  only the route to where the image will be stored, in case that helps...

After all this is said and done, I attempt to input "test" for the title, "Pittsburgh" for the location, "Active" for activity, "test" for the content, and nothing for the image which defaults to "img/".  The error that is returned is as follows:

```
    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
    ''TheTableName' (title,location,activity,content,photo) VALUES 
    ('test','Pittsburgh','A' at line 1")
```

As you can see, the content and photo seem to be completely ignored, and the activity only shows up as an "A".  Keep in mind that this all worked fine when I was using "%" instead of ",". I don't know exactly what changes between using one or the other, but apparently it's something cause now it's not working.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that the html input types are different throughout the form, but that might just be a coincidence. I'm not sure. All help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  Parameters cannot be passed for the table name in an sql statement when using the "," syntax. Therefore I had to break up the statements anywhere there was a table name and hard-code the table name variable into the statement like so:

```
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO '+theTableName+' (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5))
```

To stay safe from sql injection attacks, it's now necessary to secure the user input for the table name... but that's another story and outside the scope of this question.